# Problema con las declaraciones en PL/SQL

Tags: plsql, oracle-19c

Al intentar generar una función, me retorna este error:

**Error(9): PL/SQL: Compilation unit analysis terminated**

**Error(11,8): PLS-00320: la declaración de tipo de esta expresión está incompleta o tiene un formato incorrecto**

Claramente me está diciendo que estoy formulando mal las declaraciones, pero por mas que busco no consigo ver donde, he buscado en varias paginas el error y aun así no he conseguido una respuesta clara, mi código es este:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION FN_PROM_SALARIO(a NUMBER)
RETURN PROMEDIO_S IS 
    PROMEDIO_S NUMBER(10) :=0; 
    V_SALARIO NUMBER(10):=0;
    V_DEPARTMENTO NUMBER(4,0):=0;
BEGIN 
    SELECT ROUND((AVG(SALARY)),0), DEPARTMENT_ID INTO V_SALARIO, V_DEPARTMENTO 
    FROM EMPLOYEES
    WHERE DEPARTMENT_ID = a
    GROUP BY DEPARTMENT_ID;
    
    PROMEDIO_S:=V_SALARIO;
    RETURN PROMEDIO_S; 
END;
```

Cualquier consejo o ayuda se los agradecería mucho.

Answer (score 1):

Vale, ya me di cuenta que era, estaba poniendo "return promedio_s is", en vez de "return number is" XD